# Render text in submitted form as SO's body form

Tags: django

I wrote a form in Django's template as:

```
{% block content %}

    <form  action="{% url "learning_logs:new_entry" topic.id %}" method="POST" class='form'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form form %}

        {% buttons %}
          <button name="button" class='btn btn-primary'>add entry</button>
    {% endbuttons%}
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

[image]

It returns a plain Textarea interactive form on the browser.

How could enable my form rendering rich text and perform multiple functions as stackoverflow's question'body form.

Comment: you can use django-markdown-deux for this

Comment: [django-markdown-deux](https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux) as specified above will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a markdown widget or rich text widget. There are plenty of open source packages available that implements or integrates with Django.

For example:
https://github.com/neutronX/django-markdownx
https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote

In the end, you need to find one you like and integrate it (or write your own!)